# Want to write a fantasy magic novel can someone help with scientific guidance for energy?

Tags: magic, science-fiction

I plan to write a fantasy novel with all the usual things that we have read over the years in books. But this book will be science fiction too in the sense that what happens in this world will be explained scientifically to a certain extent.

For example, a certain highly advanced machine helps to transport our people into an alternate universe. That Earth would be MUCH bigger in size, thicker atmosphere and higher amount of gravity.

This would then support the idea of flying dragons. Since dragons can breath out fire, all plants and animals would be fire resistant. I hope you all get the idea.

Now comes the help i need. **I need a source of energy or particles, anything that is known in particle quantum physics but its very low in existence in our universe.**

That thing would exist in higher amounts in that alternate universe. Something that can be used in such a way by our mind that it would be like doing magic. Harnessing the power to change the reality, change a biology or physics or chemistry of different things in this world. All you need is a very capable person with sharp focus and will power.

The trick of doing magic would be to having a strong will power, focus, imagination and strong control over emotions. This would of-course make things very difficult, tiring and taxing on the body but possible. The magicians and wizards are thus extremely rare BUT powerful in this world.

I got this vague science fiction yet magic idea after i read about a particle physics experiment where when the scientists were observing it then it gave a different result compared to when they were Not observing it. They were forced to conclude that observation and i think a minor amount of will power (not sure about this part) was responsible for changing the outcome of the experiment.

Comment: So... What is the question?

Comment: "I got this vague science fiction yet magic idea". Yes you did. We can help you if you ask specific and well defined questions. You can [edit] the question to help us out with what *in clear terms* you need. You've given us lots of details of the big picture, and not asked a clear question, what I suggest you might do as an exercise is write down the "big picture" in a single sentence.... The actual question may just come clear then.

Comment: Need a energy source that can be explained as the fuel to use magic. Something that can have a little scientific base. Something that could exist in an alternate world in higher amounts because the lack of it in our universe does not make magic possible. Something along these lines. Maybe the laws of physics is tweaked a little different over there.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious, but are you familiar with the premise of [alternate dimensions in Stranger Things?](https://strangerthings.fandom.com/wiki/The_Upside_Down)

In the show which you should definitely watch, **scientists at Hawkins Lab open a hole into another dimension by tearing a hole in spacetime with 'normal' energy.**

It's actually been shown that if we can access other dimensions, our best bet is to tear through using either gravity or some kind of mass accelerator. Why? [Most of the universe is comprised of something called dark energy](https://science.nasa.gov/astrophysics/focus-areas/what-is-dark-energy), which is literally antigravity. To punch a hole in our reality, you need to do work against this energy. Since mass and gravity are literally the opposite of this, it's best done with these very familiar quantities.

Energy (as far as we know) is pretty in balance within our universe, so your search for this 'missing energy' may be in vain. However, and this is a stretch, our universe seems to be missing a lot of [antimatter](https://www2.lbl.gov/abc/Antimatter.html). If there's sufficient antimatter in your alternate universe, **your wizards could take advantage of superposition and collide antimatter with regular matter to produce energy in the form of gamma radiation.** This effect (called [annihilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation)) is a really interesting way of converting mass to energy. Superposition in this context is matter (and antimatter) blipping and and out of our reality. If your wizards could somehow make bigger blips, they could create an annihilation and produce energy from mass.

With all that, there's nothing wrong with keeping an air of mystery about your science. **Your average reader is probably far more invested in your story than if your explaination has been peer reviewed.**

Again, watch Stranger Things because the show does an outstanding job of balancing scientific plausibility and audience engagement through mystery. This is mind-bending physics, and I personally can get my head around your story outline without asking too many questions. Honestly, I have more questions about the dragon.

Welcome to the community, and happy worldbuilding!